# How to make Custom Apps menu available in Apple Business Manager to be able to provide/distribute private app

Tags: ios, iphone

We have an iOS app that will be privately based. We do not want to provide it publicly from Apple Store.

We already have app reviewed by Apple available in App Connect from Apple Developer account. Apple Business Manager account is also set.

Also, theoretically Organization Id from Apple Business Manager is the same as used in App Connect.

All these steps done, which is the next step to take? Shouldn't there be available an option like 'Custom Apps' with such app in Apple Business Manager Admin Panel?

What are we missing? Attached screen has its contents in Portuguese language.

[image]

Comment: In Apple Business Manager, go to "Apps and Books" and search for your private app.  Then purchase as many copies as you need

Comment: hello @Paulw11, my private does not appear in 'Apps and Books' section.